# How to get angularjs group count of array in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting my email list from server. Email object is like this:

```
var email = {"email":"hi thare", "date":"", "isRead":"false"}
```

I have a lis of this email:

```
 var emails = [{...},{...},{...},{...}]
```

I am listing this list on view by ng-repeat.

But I want to get count of isRead true and false and write them as read and unread email.

```
<span>{{???}} Count of Read Emails</span>
<span>{{???}} Count of Unread Emails</span>
```

Can I get this on view side shortly? Or I will create scope functions to calculate it.

Comment: What you can do is use filter directive to generate an array of watched object, and then display lenght value but I am sure something could suggest something more light.

Comment: You can use the filter function, but i don't think this is the most angular way to do it. : emails.filter(function(mail){return mail.isRead == "true"}).length;

Comment: @MrShibby I'd say that's Angular enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this for read and unread emails count

```
$scope.readEmailsCount = function() {
   return _.findWhere(emails, { isRead: true }).length;
};

$scope.unreadEmailsCount = function() {
   return _.findWhere(emails, { isRead: false }).length;
};
```